# python for loop to set headers

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, iteration

Hi I have a very large excel file that does not have consistent headers on each tab (ie: headers are found in row 18-23). I am trying to write a for loop that will iterate through each tab to set the headers correctly.

I have imported this with pd.read_excel and all data is in a dictionary with tab name = key, and tab data = dataframe. I got here but am not able to get the row number where the condition is true  (that will then need to be set as the header).

```
df_GRID=pd.read_excel(input_GRID, sheet_name=df_GRID_tabs, header=0)

for key,values in df_GRID.items():
    print(key,values.iloc[:, 0] == '8760 Time Series')
```

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
print(key, np.where(values.iloc[:,0] == '8760 Time Series')[0][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not that useful to you, but in my case, I use `xls2csv.py` from [HERE](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv). It does a lot of useful things like allow stripping empty lines, etc.

I make a pipeline of XLSX -> CSV -> Edited_CSV -> Processing...

To turn CSV -> Edited_CSV, I just loop through the rows looking for an indication of headers, something like this:

```
header_seen = False
outlines = []
with open(csvfile, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
  reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
  for line in list(reader):
    if not header_seen:
      if line[0] == 'PATTERN':
        header_seen = True
        outlines.append(line)
    else:
      outlines.append(line)
```